# Can I safely plug a 13amp washing machine into a 15amp power socket?

Tags: electrical

I have a 15 Amp wall socket and recently bought a washing machine with a 13 Amp plug. Can I plug the washing machine into the 15 Amp wall socket using an 3 round-pin to 3 square pin adapter?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this plug (a BS 1363)

[image]

and this BS 546 socket

[image]

To convert a 1363 plug to a 546 socket, this fused adapter (13A) can be safely used:

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to post this as a comment?

Comment: hoping to get a comment answer, to finish the answer, wanted a verify, will post it into question, if true...

Comment: Thank you, Mr HerrBag, for your answer so clearly illustrated with photos. It was reassuring. I was told that I should not use an adaptor but my "layman's" logic told me it should be fine since the equipment being plugged in requires a lower Amp that what the wall socket was built for. It would be a problem if it's the other way around, wouldn't it? Thanks again.

Comment: The washing machine comes with the 13A UK fused square pin plug. But my wall socket is the 15 A BS 546 round pin type. So can I just use the adapter as HerrBag suggested? I was not able to find a fused adapter in the hardware store though. Is it OK to use an unfused adapter in this case? I do not want to change the washing machine's square pin plug to a round pin one because that might void the warranty of the washing machine. (I'm in Singapore).

Comment: @Joy If you'd like to ask for clarification on an answer, please use the "**add comment**" button.

Comment: While you are safe using an unfused adaptor with a fused cable, I would recommend getting the fused adapter, because down-the-road, someone else may borrow the adapter and use it with a non-fused cable.  The (potential) extra 2Amps might be enough to cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as the convertor in the middle is marked to handle **at least 13 Amps** then you will be fine

Alternative

You can also cut off the original plug "South Africa?" and install a UK style style (at least 13 Amp) plug onto it without any problems.

Round prong wiring. Rare to contain a fuse unless you specifically buy one.

[image]

**Although if you are using something that is going to draw near 13Amps (2500Watts+) then change the plug to the one you need. Using converters for heaters, stoves, hair dryers or other heavy appliances is a very bad idea. Do not even consider using it temporarily.**

Comment: Do you recommend using fused convertors/fused rewire plugs is this situation?

Comment: As far as I know the round prong (South Africa type) do not contain fuses over the counter but they are available on request. The wall socket also contain no fuse. Some converters are fused but if using a fused UK type plug, there is no requirement to have a fused converter as it will be redundant. If changing to a UK plug you will not find an unfused one and it must be there. If in South Africa, there is no requirement to have the SA plugs fused at all but they MUST be earthed!